# What version of Compiz will be installed in 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, compiz

I want to install Ubuntu 10.10 because I don't like Unity. If I install compiz fusion via terminal, will it be the 0.8 version, or the latest one, which is 0.9.6?

Comment: see here http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/compiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jason, knowing the real reason you want to do this, from your previous questions, let me first give you a warning before answering. Compiz 0.8.x is not maintained any more (beyond simple bug fixes). As I have said over and over and over... Compiz-fusion is dead, and the project is now called Compiz.

That said, if you install 10.10, you will be getting Compiz 0.8.6 (it is installed by default, you don't have to install Compiz from the terminal on **any** version of Ubuntu since 7.10!). However, while some of the plugins you are so excited about may work, many of them will cause Compiz to become unstable, crash, and God knows what else (I'm speaking from experience, not just from guessing - I used to run just about every plugin I could find).

Again let me reiterate some things:

- Compiz fusion is dead and it is now Compiz.
- Compiz 0.8.6 is not maintained, and 0.9.x plugins will not work with it (and vice versa).
- You do not have to use Unity in 11.10 or 11.04. You can install another desktop environment like XFCE or GNOME Classic.
- Installing unsupported plugins is not recommended for someone with little Linux experience in general - you might (pretty much *will*) break things you can't fix.
- No one is taking your choice away, but I would rather warn you harshly than let you jump off a bridge.

That said - if you want to go ahead, you can install 10.10. Just remember that half of what you wanted to do according to your other questions might end up breaking the system if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you for being such a help to me, @roland-taylor. Is there any way that I can contact you, Facebook perhaps?

Comment: @jasoncruz98 yes, I'm on facebook and G+, and on jabber etc. My info is on my profile page (click on my name) or on http://about.met/rolandixor

Comment: One important thing you forgot to add: Compiz 0.9.x is not yet stable. BTW, do you have a source for 0.8.x not being maintained any more?

Comment: @user142: I didn't forget to mention that; it is stable.

Comment: @user142 it is.

Comment: @RolandTaylor Have a look at http://wiki.compiz.org/ or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz. And why do you think other Linux distributions (like Arch for example) are still using 0.8.x? Cheers

Comment: @user142 you used outdated sources (I read both of those just about a week ago). They have not been updated to reflect the fact that 0.9.x is now stable enough to be used in a distro (and btw Ubuntu uses 0.9.6+ in 11.10). Why else would Ubuntu use it (even for an upcoming LTS release?) If you think I'm wrong, that's fine, but this is not a forum.

Answer (score 3):

It is the old 0.8 series. At the moment it is 0.8.6 as pointed out by Takkat.